# Masonry uneven grid with jQuery

Tags: html, css, wordpress, jquery-plugins, masonry

I've got a problem and was hoping you guys could help me out;

For a project I'm working on I want to create an uneven grid in a WordPress template. For the grid, I'm using Desandro's Masonry.js which is a lovely library for creating flexible grids.

Currently, I have all wordpress content displayed as a straight horizontal grid, like so:

[even grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ajme.jpg)

However, my eventual goal is to have the grid displayed as following:

[uneven grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FultK.jpg)

To give you an idea of how I currently have my grid setup here's a chunk of the code:

I'm using the following WordPress loop for the majority of the grid display:

```
<main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">   
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) :
    if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <?php
    endif;
    /* Start the Loop */
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-masonry', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
else :
    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
endif; ?>
```

Which selects from the following content-part:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="grid-item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 grid-item-content-background">
                <div class="grid-item-content-background">
                    <div class="front-page-grid-item-tag">
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-container">
                        <i class="fa-border-circle glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
                    </div>

                    <!-- post-tags -->
                    <div class="tags-container">
                    <?php $tags = wp_get_post_tags( $post->ID );
                        $html = '';
                        foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
                            $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );        
                            $html .= "<div class='tag-display tag-icon-{$tag->slug}'></div>";
                        }
                        echo $html; ?>

                        <h4 class="front-page-category">
                            <?php foreach( (get_the_category()) as $category ) { echo $category->cat_name . ' '; } ?>

                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    <!-- .post-tags -->

                    <div class="grid-item-content">
                        <div class="grid-item-content-thumbnail" 
                             <?php 
                             if ( $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id()) {
                                if ($image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'normal-bg'))
                                    printf('style="background-image: url(%s);"', $image_src[0]);     
                             } ?>>
                            <div class="frontpage-overlay frontpage-overlay-trigger">
                                <div class="frontpage-article-text-container">
                                    <h2 class="front-page-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                                    <h3 class="front-page-subtitle">
                                        <?php { 
                                        $subtitle = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, 'subtitle', $single = true ); 
                                        if ( $subtitle !== '' ) echo $subtitle;
                                        elseif ( $subtitle == '' ) echo '<!-- no subtitle set -->'; } ?>

                                    </h3>
                                </div><!-- .front-page-article-text-container -->
                            </div><!-- .frontpage-overlay -->
                        </div><!-- .grid-item-content-thumbnail -->
                    </div><!-- .grid-item-content -->
                </div><!-- .grid-item-content-background -->
            </div><!-- .grid-item -->
        </div><!-- .row -->
    </a>
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Now I've noticed that Masonry uses absolute positioning on the .grid-item class to position elements from top: 0px and left: 0%. Would it at all be possible to have masonry instead start elements from, say, 40px top on the uneven elements inside the grid? Making the grid effectively uneven?

Normally I would simply encapsulate the left side of the grid within a container with an additional margin-top, but sadly I've been unable to achieve that. I've also tried setting all uneven children of the grid to an additional margin-top using CSS, but that was to no avail either (which probably has something to do with the absolute positioning Masonry does).

I've been fussing about this for hours on end. If somebody could assist me that would be really appreciated!

Thank you!

Update:
Due to the used library using absolute positioning, any CSS edits are uneffective. I assume that I'll be needing a jQuery hack that'll set the top of the first element to top: 40px instead of the top: 0; but I have no clue where to start. If anybody can help me that'd be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I eventually found the solution by adding the following jQuery:

```
jQuery( '.grid-item:even' ).css( 'margin-top', '40px' );
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to leverage the `:nth-of-type()` CSS selector. If these elements are rendering in the expected order, you would use `:nth-of-type(odd)` to select the first column. Adding `margin-top:40px;` to drop every element in that column.

If the grid elements are not rendered in the expected order, you may have to modify `Masonry.js` or write your own JS to find and modify the `top` positioning of the left column grid elements.

Comment: Hello Hopkins, thank you for your advice! Sadly, this did not work due to the absolute positioning of the grid! Perhaps you have some other suggestions?

Comment: @Extricate I didn't realize that every element was absolutely positioned. Will the grid always be two columns?

Comment: No upon collapsing to bootstraps' extra small devices it'll become one full-width column. In every other scenario it's two columns!

Comment: @Extricate answer has been updated. Try the `nth-of-type` selector. If that doesn't work, you'll need to look into overriding the positioning set by `Masonry.js`. I'd look for usage of `.top` in the `Masonry.js` file to identify where they are setting that value.

Comment: Thanks again Hopkins! Yes, I've also tried the nth-of-type selector to select every uneven element, but again the absolute positioning ruins the party. I'll have a look into the Masonry code itself, thanks for the pointers!